# How can i receive a payment method nonce from client In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, braintree

How can i receive a payment method nonce from client in Magento ver. 2.

If transaction is processed using **braintree payment method**. Please can anyone

Help me in solving Question.

Comment: where do you want this info?

Comment: Hi @Priyank, I need to show these in controller or model file.

Answer (score 0):

I searched [Magento2's GitHub repo](https://github.com/magento/magento2), and I think [the `getPaymentMethodNonce` function](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/app/code/Magento/Braintree/view/adminhtml/web/js/vault.js#L107) is what you need.